# How to end session through Dialogflow api v2 webhook response?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I am developing Google Assistant Action (for google home) using the Dialogflow and the [API v2](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookResponse) webhooks

I am having trouble finding how to end session!

There was `expectUserResponse` in [API v1](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/webhook), there is `shouldEndSession` on Alexa, but I can not find anything similar for Dialogflow v2.

Answer (score 1):

In the Dialogflow console, select the intent you want, and go to the Responses section.

Select `Set this intent as end of conversation`.

You do not need to specify a response to send back (you can do that in your code as long as Fulfillment is set to `Enable webhook call for this intent`)

Answer (score 0):

For Dialogflow v2 the `expectUserResponse` attribute still works for ending a conversation on Actions on Google, its just in a slightly different place (`...` indicates the rest of your Actions on Google payload):

```
{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "payload": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        ...
      },
      "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE"
    }
  ]
}
```